# TAG_ID3 (from Bass 2.4.4) doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, c++builder-2010, bass, bass.dll

I'm trying to read ID3v1 tags from mp3 files using "BASS.dll"(via bass.lib and bass.h). 
It works fine until .mp3 file has title (or artist) has 30 characters. 
Instead 
`Happy Times (Feat. Margaux Bos` 
 I get `Happy Times (Feat. Margaux BosEmigrate` 
with `Emigrate` added (that's artist tag).

How to make it work properly, without adding artist tag?
Here is my source code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit2.h"
#include "bass.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    BASS_Init(-1, 44000, 0, 0, 0);

    if(OpenDialog1->Execute())
    {
       HSTREAM stream = BASS_StreamCreateFile(false, OpenDialog1->FileName.c_str(), 0, 0, 0);
       TAG_ID3 *tags = (TAG_ID3*)BASS_ChannelGetTags(stream, BASS_TAG_ID3);
       Edit1->Text = tags->title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text fields of the [`TAG_ID3`](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/TAG_ID3.html) struct are not guaranteed to be null terminated, but your code is treating them as if they are, so it ends up reading into the next field when a null terminator is not present.  To fix that, you have to take their max lengths into account, eg:

```
Edit1->Text = AnsiString().sprintf("%.*s", sizeof(tags->title), tags->title);
```

Or:

```
Edit1->Text = AnsiString(tags->title, sizeof(tags->title)).TrimRight();
```

Same with all of other text fields:

- `id`: 3 chars
- `title`: 30 chars
- `artist`: 30 chars
- `album`: 30 chars
- `year`: 4 chars
- `comment`: 30 chars

You can use a simple template wrapper to help you:

```
template<size_t N>
String toString(char (&arr)[N])
{
    return AnsiString().sprintf("%.*s", N, arr); 
    /* or:
    return AnsiString(arr, N).TrimRight();
    */
}

Edit1->Text = toString(tags->title);
```

Note that the `comment` field has an additional caveat to watch out for:

> If the 30th character is non-null whilst the 29th character is null, then the 30th character is the track number and the comment is limited to the first 28 characters.

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer!